# Julia: How do I sum the elements of a matrix together?

Tags: julia

I have a matrix C of type Matrix{Float64} with 20x10 elements.

I need to sum the 10 elements to get a vector of size 20x1 (or 1x20).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sum()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.sum) and specify the dimension :

```
sum(A, dims=2)
```

where `A` is your `Matrix`. In this case `1` would sum along columns and `2` would sum along rows.

Comment: I get an error: ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: objects of type Matrix{Float64} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.

Comment: @qwebfub3i4u You need to specify the dimensions as a named argument `dims`

Comment: Note that this (specifying the `dims` argument) works for many other functions than sum, like e.g. `minimum`, `maximum` and other more advanced... and works for generic n-dimensional arrays, not just matrices.

Comment: `sum(f, X)` is interpreted as if it should apply `f` to each element in `X`. In your case that means it will try to do `A(2)`, causing the error. I recommend using a semicolon before keyword arguments: `sum(A; dims=2)`, it improves clarity and reduces the risk of bugs.